# Android: making tap events outside of my application

Tags: android

I want to run my application, hit a button, and then be able to minimize my app, and do anything else on my phone. But after I've hit that button, I want to be able to duplicate every click I make.

So after I've hit the button, say I switch over to a painting app. If I press down on the screen to start painting, it also places down a second touch a few pixels away, to almost simulate two pens taped together.

Is receiving and making touch events outside of my app possible? If so, what route should I take to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is receiving and making touch events outside of my app possible?

Not generally, for security reasons. Apps cannot spy on other app's input, nor can apps fake input into other apps.

The accessibility APIs offer some support for this sort of thing, but not to the level of individual touch events.